# Appium code using visual studio

Tags: appium

I have tried to run this piece of code in Visual studio using appium, but i get an error Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver'

Comment: "this piece of code", are you missing something there?

Comment: Please share the piece of code